# Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page

Tags: wordpress

I realize there is other threads on this topic but there solutions and problems are different from mine.

Im able to login to wp-admin correctly
All seems normal but the abilty to (add plugin) or theme or anything has been wiped.

you can look at plugins but there is no way to add a new one.
Same goes for widgets, and themes.

Also. 
You cant access things like update core.

you just get a default message
Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

Iv checked the mysql database and all seems fine.
With the user_meta and users

Iv deleted all plugins
Iv deleted all themes.
There is no issue with Wp memory

its basically just a default install of wordpress at this point.

Im not sure what could be causing this.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a wordpress or a server error? Which HTTP statuscode do you get? Do your folders on the server have the appropriate file permissions?

Comment: No http status code
If i check console i get
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403

and as far as i know they havent changed my permissions

Comment: Maybe your hoster can help you better than we can. It seems like a misconfiguration maybe in Apache or nginx or in .htaccess or with the folder permissions. If you could post the logs and the folder listing and everything it would be helpful